# Should we tag our SVN repo after every successful CI build?

Tags: svn, version-control, continuous-integration, teamcity

Tags in SVN are cheap.  Are they cheap enough to enable us to tag every successful build that pops out of our CI box (TeamCity, if that makes any difference)?

Comment: What would be the payback for tagging every build? Tags are usually used to highlight "special"/"important" points in your project's history - and are usually static/read-only. Many tags would add more clutter making it difficult for you to find what you're looking for

Comment: When we do a build, our QA department pick the next available build from the CI box.  They then spend some time manually testing it and at some point in the future say "Yes, build 1.2.3.4 is OK for production".  We need a way of identifying version 1.2.3.4 in source control.

Comment: You know exact revision of build. Why you need tags?

Comment: there is some other built-in identifier to uniquely identify a build.. You could use revision numbers / changeset id / a shared assembly version (which is incremented with every build)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is NO. This is not SVN specific, it is just good practice specific.

CI builds shouldn't increment build or version numbers - they are just a sanity check that everything **builds** (hey, it may not **run** though). There is absolutely no point in tagging a CI build.

**Edit:**

> our QA department pick the next available build from the CI box

Your QA department shouldn't be touching a CI build, instead they should be working with **release quality** builds, which frequently have more done to them than CI builds (i.e. version numbers have been inserted where appropriate, compilation has been done in Release mode instead of Debug, etc). Remember that CI builds may compile, but they can be a pile of junk, depending on what has been checked in to the source repository.
It sounds like what you refer to as the *CI build* should just be called *the build*, as it is the only one you are doing. It is a bit of work to put together a good set of builds, but it is worth the effort, There are a number of tutorials and white papers out there about this, invest some time and read up on it, then give your QA department the smack every time they utter the words *"CI build"* (as those builds should be for developers use only).

---

**Further edit:**

a couple of people have commented *"why can't a CI build be release quality?"*. I will try to answer this in a succinct way without turning this into a discussion unsuitable for SO. Let me say first-up that of course a CI build can be release quality. If you can achieve this then more power to you, award yourself a medal. If you are in this category then i would guess that you are on a small team with a slowly changing codebase.

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration):

> *Normal practice is to trigger these builds by every commit to a repository, rather than a periodically scheduled build. The practicalities of doing this in a multi-developer environment of rapid commits are such that it's usual to trigger a short timer after each commit, then to start a build when either this timer expires, or after a rather longer interval since the last build.*

And to quote [Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html):

> *Continuous Integration is a software development practice where members of a team integrate their work frequently, usually each person integrates at least daily - leading to multiple integrations per day. Each integration is verified by an automated build (including test) to detect integration errors as quickly as possible.*

Neither of those say that a CI build *shouldn't* be release quality. **But nor do either of them say that it should be.**

When working in a reasonable size team who are working off the same branch, it quickly becomes impractical to achieve release quality with every CI build. CI builds are invariably started a small period of time after a check-in, there is no guarantee that a team member has actually finished their check-in, or that someone else hasn't started when that timer ticks over and the build starts.

Another thought to bear in mind is that when working on a larger team, a routine pratice is to do CI builds on the development branch, while Release/QA quality builds are done off a Release or QA branch. This enables the dev team to continue implementing features without polluting the builds that QA will be testing - when the features are complete then they get merged across to the branch that the QA team takes their builds from.

<sub>I hope this explains my comment about QA teams not working with CI builds. Any further discussion should really take place on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or elsewhere.</sub>

Comment: Why can't a CI build be of release quality?

Comment: Every build should be release quality - potentially shippable. But there is no good reason to tag every build.

Comment: @Ivo, @rarous, i have added a further edit to explain what i mean. In a nutshell, it all comes down to what is practical and what isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Since Subversion has essentially built-in tag in the global revision number for each commits, this isn't necessary.

You usually tag for marking a significant step, not for keeping track of a continuous process.